# Uninstall eclipse plugin - linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and in order to test it I have to install it into my eclipse application regularly. However as I dont't want to change the version of my plugin every time I want to test a new feature I always uninstalled the plugin from within eclipse and afterwards I'd go to the eclipse folder and delete my plugin out of the `plugins` folder (and delete the respective entries in the eclipse XML-files).

That worked great in windows but I have recently switched to Linux (Mint) and I just found out that my plugin is no longer located in the `plugins` folder inside the eclipse program directory. Therefore I can't really delete the old plugin whcih then prevents the new version of the plugin from installing properly.

Does anyone have an idea about where eclipse copies the installed plugin or a differerent approch to actually completely uninstall (delete) an installed eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after searching through my whole filesystem I found it out myself.
Eclipse has a hidden folder in the home directory named `.eclipse` in which each installed eclipse version has it's sub-directory and in there there is also a `plugins` and a `features` folder that then contain the externally installed plugins and features.
It also contains the corresponding `artifacts.xml`.

I'm not sure whether this behaviour is specific to the Linux Mint OS or rather a new "feature" of Eclipse `Neon` but if anyone is having the same problem that's were I found it.

Answer (score 1):

Help -> Installation Detail.
Then click the plugin you want removed then press "Uninstall...".

*Note: there is a "Plug-ins" tab in the Installation Detail dialog. This is misleading; you are not to click it.*

Ps. It might be easier to test the plugin, during development, on a [run-time workbench.](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_my_plug-in_in_another_instance_of_Eclipse%3F)

Comment: Yes but the problem with that method is that it doesn't actually remove the plugins and if I then try to install the updated plugin (that still has the same version numbers) eclipse tries to be smart and uses the old plugin it still has stored in it's filesystem and therefore the new plugin does not get installed or (even worse) gets only partly installed and that messes up everything. And yes I do test my plugin in a runtime-environment but there are some things that behave differently when being run from a class file in the filsesystem and when being run from a jar.